# SpringXD-issue in mysql as source .FAILED TO VALIDATE A NEWLY ESTABLISHED CONNECTION

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I am creating a spring xd stream like below :

```
stream create foo --definition "jdbc --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --query='select * from employee' |hdfs --inputType=text/plain --rollover=200" --deploy
```

I am able to get the data in hdfs..ButI am getting error in the logs like below..Any reason for this kind of error..
The output is here:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        216 2015-10-15 08:45 /xd/foo/foo-34.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        216 2015-10-15 08:45 /xd/foo/foo-35.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        216 2015-10-15 08:45 /xd/foo/foo-36.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs          0 2015-10-15 08:45 /xd/foo/foo-37.txt.tmp
```

But the error is this in the log file

```
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204)
        ... 21 more

2015-10-15 08:42:04,839 1.1.2.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-9 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:245)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:457)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:186)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204)
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this issue as well at times. I opened a JIRA issue to look into this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3620

In the meantime you can work around this by specifying "--testOnBorrow=false" when creating the job or the stream.

Comment: also happened to me with PostgreSQL